# Evaluate $\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\, dx$$

I tried substitution but failed miserably.

Comment: Did you try trig sub?

Comment: Maybe $x = \text{sinh}(t)$?

Comment: Or did you try substituting $x=\tan(u)$, if you are not familiar with hyperbolic functions?

Comment: Also Euler's first substitution: $$\sqrt{1+x^2}=x+t$$

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be solved by [a call to Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[Sqrt[1%2Bx^2]%2Fx%2Cx]).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as
$$\int \frac{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^2}\,dx,$$ and let $u^2=1+x^2$.  Then $x\,dx=u\,du$, and we end up with
$$\int \frac{u^2}{u^2-1}\,du,$$
 which is probably familiar. Start by noting that $\frac{u^2}{u^2-1}=1+\frac{1}{u^2-1}$.

Comment: The integrand can be decomposed as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{u-1}+\frac{1}{u+1}\right)
$$
+1 Prof! (ô‿ô)

Comment: Ahh, use U-substitution!

Comment: I had a typo. We divide, then use your method.

Comment: @Great one, I got the antiderivative in a round about method, hats off!!

Comment: Even if you made a typo, no one will downvote you and I still upvote your answer (It seems *downvote* and *upvote* not verbs or words in English)

Comment: A typo that does not affect the mathematics should not incur a negative vote, but in a formula it can be a different matter. I personally do not cast negative votes, leaving comments instead, but negative votes are part of the SE structure.

Comment: And the one who downvote should be gentle enough to leave a comment

Comment: @AndréNicolas Very nice substitution. If I were you (and avoiding the trig/hyperbolic substitution route altogether, for simplicity), I would replace the last sentence with "Start by noting that $$\frac{u^2}{u^2-1} \equiv 1+\frac{1}{2(u-1)}-\frac{1}{2(u+1)} \quad$$", as this can be integrated immediately (as opposed to $$1+\frac{1}{u^2-1}$$ which requires either a hyperbolic substitution or partial fractions).

Comment: In dealing with homework-style questions, I like to leave something for OP to do. In fact I dithered a bit about mentioning the division, but decided to do it since students so often forget about that in the partial fractions process. I thought that OP would see that what remained was a partial fractions problem, and that if OP ran into trouble at the end then OP could send a message.

Answer (score 5):

Using Euler substitution by setting $\sqrt{1+x^2}=t-x$ then we have
$$
x=\frac{t^2-1}{2t}\qquad\Rightarrow\quad dx=\frac{1+t^2}{2t^2}\ dt.
$$
Hence
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\ dx&=\int\frac{\left(1+t^2\right)^2}{2t^2}\ dt\\
&=\int\left[\frac1{2}-\frac1{t+1}+\frac1{t-1}-\frac1{2t^2}\right]\ dt.
\end{align}
The rest part should be easy.

Answer (score 4):

If we set $x=\sinh t$ we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I &=& \int\frac{\cosh^2 t}{\sinh t}\,dt = \cosh t+\int\frac{dt}{\sinh t}=\cosh t+\int \frac{\cosh\frac{t}{2}}{\sinh\frac{t}{2}}\cdot\frac{dt}{2\cosh^2\frac{t}{2}}\\&=&\sqrt{1+x^2}+\log\tanh\frac{t}{2}=\sqrt{1+x^2}+\log\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right).\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Try drawing a right triangle. Label one leg as "1" and the other leg as "x". We can solve for the hypotenuse of this triangle and get $\sqrt{1+x^{2}}$. Now assign a $\theta$ somewhere in the triangle so long as it is not the $90$ degree angle of our right triangle (I put my $\theta$ across from the leg marked "x"). If you do this, you should get the following relations: $$\sec(\theta)=\sqrt{1+x^{2}},\ \tan(\theta)=x,\ dx=\sec^{2}(\theta)d\theta$$ Now we can rewrite the integral as $$\int \! \frac{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x=\int \! \frac{\sec(\theta)}{\tan(\theta)}sec^{2}(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta=\int \! \sec^{2}(\theta)\csc(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta$$ See if you can integrate it from here. It looks like one of those integrals that may need to be looked up in the back of a calc book

Comment: Now you can use $u=\csc\theta, dv=\sec^{2}\theta d\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\tan t$ so we have $$\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x} dx=\int\csc t dt+\int \frac{\sin t}{\cos^2 t}  dt=\ln|\csc t-\cot(t)|+\frac{1}{\cos t}+c$$

Comment: I believe you want a + sign in front of the 2nd term.

Answer (score 2):

Put $$x = \tan y\, \Longrightarrow\,  dx = \sec^{2}y\,dy$$

Substituting this you will get $$I = \int \frac{sec^{3}y}{tany} dy$$

Now substitute $$\sec y = v\, \Longrightarrow\,  \sec y\tan y\,dy = dv\,  \Longrightarrow\, dy = \frac{dv}{\sec y\tan y}$$

Now $$I = \int \frac{v^3}{v(v^2-1)}dv$$

$$I = \int \frac{v^2}{v^2 - 1} dv$$
$$I = \int \frac{v^2-1 + 1}{v^2-1} dv$$

$$I = \int dv +\int \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{1}{v-1} - \frac{1}{v+1}\right]dv$$

$$I = v + \frac{1}{2}\bigg[ \ln|v-1| - \ln|v+1|\bigg]+C.$$

Comment: Now, it looks better. Make sure you put a slash, `\\`, before trig & log function. +1 (ô‿ô)

Comment: @V-Moy, Thank you, sir.

Comment: You should be called Sir, not me.